# Flow for guest user to create a task

Tags: community, visual-workflow, tasks, guest-user, screen-flow

I have created a simple Screen Flow that takes some inputs and creates a task.  I am putting it on a public site in a community.  When the flow runs it throws an error of "An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more information." The flow works perfectly for a standard salesforce user but not for the site guest user.

Comment: Have you checked the guest user permissions for the objects and fields you reference in the flow?  You can also set a debug log to try to get more detail on the error.

Comment: Please check the object permission and FLS otherwise run the flow in without sharing context.